# Firestore db is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So am trying to create a simple form web app where users can fill details and onclick it should save in firestore but am not able to initialise firestore properly When I try to run the function it says db is not defined here's my code

HTML

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.9.1/firebase-app.js"></script> 
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.9.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script> 
  <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="background" class="main_card">
    <div id="main" class="main_content" style="display: none">
      <div class ="info">
        <h1 class="h1">H1</h1>
        <h2 class="h2">H2</h2>
        <h1 class="h1">Name and Name</h1>
          <p class= "line p">________________________________________</p>
          <h2 class="h2">The Details</h2>
          <p class="p">Date</p>
          <p class="p">Time</p>
          <br>
          <h2 class="h2">Random text</h2>
          <p class="p">Random text</p>
          <p class="p">Address</p>
          <p class= "line p">________________________________________</p>
        <input id="namefield" type="text" placeholder="Name" required>
        <input id="numberfield" type="number" placeholder="No of Guests" required>
      </div>
      <button class ="regret">Regret</button>
      <button class ="accept" onclick="WriteData();">Accept</button>//Here the function calls the JS function

  </div>
  
<script> 
  // Your web app's Firebase configuration 
  var config = {
      apiKey: "My API KEY",
      authDomain: "DOMAIN",
      projectId: "PROJECT ID",
      storageBucket: "storageBucket",
      messagingSenderId: "messagingSenderId",
      appId: "appId",
      measurementId: "G-measurementId"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase 
  firebase.initializeApp(config); 
  firebase.analytics();
  const db = firebase.firestore(); 

  db.settings({ timestampsInSnapshot: true });
</script>

<script src="backend.js"></script>
  
</body>

</html>
```

backend.js

```
function WriteData(){
  
  var name = document.getElementById("namefield").value;
  var people = document.getElementById("numberfield").value;
  db.collection('RSVP').add({ // The error arises here "db is not defined"
    name: name, 
    people: people,
  }).then((docref) => { console.log("Document writted with ID: ", docref.id);}).catch((error) => { console.log("Error adding document: ", error);

  }); 
}
```

Hope these are necessary information.

New Error

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://firestore.googleapis.com/google.firestore.v1.Firestore/Write/channel?database=projects%2Frsvp-for-tipsy-and-ixy%2Fdatabases%2F(default)&VER=8&RID=65860&CVER=22&X-HTTP-Session-Id=gsessionid&%24httpHeaders=X-Goog-Api-Client%3Agl-js%2F%20fire%2F8.6.1%0D%0AContent-Type%3Atext%2Fplain%0D%0AX-Firebase-GMPID%3A1%3A321206967611%3Aweb%3Adbefee0e935d6e0931ab1e%0D%0A&zx=q0x6d2syb2od&t=1' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'https://127.0.0.1:5500' that is not equal to the supplied origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to align the version numbers of the Firebase libraries:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.9.1/firebase-app.js"></script> 
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.9.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
```

Shall be changed to

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-app.js"></script> 
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
```

see that they all point to version 8.6.1.

Note that it is not the latest version of the JS SDK v8. See https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js

Comment: Am sorry your answer has helped me. I have done some changes now its working but I have a new error that I have edited in question

Comment: What happens if you try to deploy the app to Firebase hosting?

Comment: Yes now it works I have hosted in firebase hosting as you said and works like charm Thank you so much :)